# Magento Newbie. Promotions stop working everyday

Tags: magento, e-commerce, cron

So we have a Magento site which has two promotions running. They are set to run for a month but somehow stop working everyday and constantly need to be reapplied.

I'm completely new to Magento so no idea what code if any I need to put on here but I have full access to all the site files, database and admin console so adding extra info shouldn't be an issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem a while ago and wasn't able to find a solution that kept re-applying the rules on a daily basis.

In the end I added a cron job to the server that executed a file everyday at midnight that looked something like this:

```
<?php
  require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/Mage.php';
  Mage::init();

  $catalogRuleModel = Mage::getModel('catalogrule/rule');
  $catalogRuleModel->applyAll();
?>
```

So far I haven't had any problems with promotions not being applied. Hope this maybe of help.